# Get some parent element ID in order to send to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have this table:

```
<table id="tblId">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>View Name</th>
                <th>View Description</th>                       
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="1">
                    <td>Name</td>                    
                    <td><span onclick="jsFunction()">description</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="2">
                    <td>Name</td>                    
                    <td><span onclick="jsFunction()">description</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

In the `onclick` event of each span I need to send the js function the row id of that specific row. How do I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way is you can send "sender" data with jsFunction as below,

```
... onclick="jsFunction(this)" ....
```

In your jsFunction you can find tr element,

```
    function jsFunction(sender){
        var tr = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
        alert( tr.getAttribute('id') );
    }
```